# ypeError: fn is not a function in runtime-core.esm-bundler.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, webpack-5, vuejs3-composition-api

I am using vue3 with webpack5. I have create vue alias for vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js in webpack configuration like this :
[image]

But still i am getting an error like :
[image]

I am not sure why i am getting this error. Any idea what exactly am i missing here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks.